# Read and write Clob data using python and cx_oracle

Tags: python, json, oracle, clob, cx-oracle

Am trying to read Clob data from test db and inserting it in dev db. Am able to do that but the performance is very poor.
For 100K rows its taking 8 to 12 hours, and running it from my local machine.
Am wondering if my approach is correct or is there any better way in doing it.
Below is my code after connections:

```
for row in rows.fetchall()
   x = []
   data = row.read
   json_data = json.loads(data)
   x.append(json_data)
```

This is how am doing it. Just wanted to know if there is any better way to do it.
Stack : Python, OracleDB, cx_oracle, json
Thanks

Comment: For a start, `print` is really expensive. You could try `for x, row in enumerate(rows.fetchall()):` and then hide the `print` under `if x % 10000 == 0: print row` but I also don't think it's enough to explain the slowness

Comment: Also, I think you could probably just iterate through the cursor without using `.fetchall()`. After that I have no familiarity with `Clob` to say whether you could get around using `json.loads()` on each row.

Comment: Try fetching the LOBs as shown in https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues/63#issuecomment-322532071  Also see section 7 (LOBS) in the tutorial https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/tutorial/Python-and-Oracle-Database-12c-Scripting-for-the-Future.html

Answer (score 2):

From the cx_Oracle [sample](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLongs.py) the following code is what you want to use. This should dramatically improve performance!

```
def OutputTypeHandler(cursor, name, defaultType, size, precision, scale):
    if defaultType == cx_Oracle.CLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_STRING, arraysize = cursor.arraysize)
    elif defaultType == cx_Oracle.BLOB:
        return cursor.var(cx_Oracle.LONG_BINARY, arraysize = cursor.arraysize)

conn = cx_Oracle.Connection("user/pw@dsn")
conn.outputtypehandler = OutputTypeHandler
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("""
        select CLOBColumn
        from SomeTable""")
json_data = [json.loads(s) for s, in cursor]
```

Comment: OutputTypeHandler is not called when you use `cursor.callproc()`. is it normal? how to handle on that scenario?

Comment: `cursor.callproc()` uses PL/SQL and that requires the use of CLOBs, unfortunately!